SharePoint List Power Apps Custom Form - URL Field resets form on failure instead of displaying error
I am creating a custom form for a sharepoint list in power apps. In the sharepoint list, I have a URL type column. I have added that card into the custom form in power apps, however when I try to use the custom form and enter in a non url into the url card, I get the error at the top of the form:

"Network error when using Patch function: The requested operation is invalid."

If I am editing an existing row, then it resets the form as well.
I saw another post explaining how to display an error with regex:
IsMatch(Object.Text, "(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$")
But I am unsure how to block the form submitting (because this brings up that error that users won't understand and also resets the form). Does anyone know how to do this?

Difficult to pin-point your issue without knowing more about your set-up. Suggest you have a look at https://www.matthewdevaney.com/power-apps-patch-function-error-handling/

On submit button try this formula
If(IsMatch(DataCardValue24.Text, "(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$")=true,SubmitForm(EditForm1),Notify("Proper Url must be entered in URL field"))


